# NSUserDefaults Saving only last entered data

Tags: ios, iphone, nsuserdefaults

I am saving Textfield text using NSUserDefaults on button click  in ViewController2
 My code is

```
ButtonClick()
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:keyWordField.text forKey:@"Keywords"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}

Then ViewDidLoad method i am Retrieving like this
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

NSUserDefaults *userDefaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[keyWordArray addObject:[userDefaults objectForKey:@"Keywords"]];
[userDefaults synchronize];

}
```

Here i am assigning this keyWordArray to tableview
like `cell.textlabel.text =[keyWordArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

```
First i entered text(First) in textfield and click button it is showing in table like
     First
Second time i entered text (second) in textfield and click button it is showing table like
      First
      Second
Here everything working fine. The problem is when i come to viewController2 from ViewController1. It is showing last entered value only 
like
      Second
```

what going wrong here?

Comment: don't use synchronize in data fetch time

Comment: you enter textfield value using same key so its ovrride the previous value of nsuserdefault so you have to enter different key value.

Comment: In userdefaults you are saving only last text. you need to save the keyWordArray as object and retrieve the object in wherever you need it.

Comment: @RAJA i want to save entire array but is is getting saved last object only that is my problem

Comment: keyWordField.text saves only the text of the textfield. it's a string. not array object.

Comment: where you declared your keyWordArray

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
- (IBAction)buttonclick:(id)sender {

[keyWordArray addObject:keyWordField.text];
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:keyWordArray forKey:@"Keywords"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
[selt.tableView reload];  //reload the table every time a new text is added
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
 if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Keywords"]==nil){
  keyWordArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 }
 else{
 keyWordArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Keywords"];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
- (IBAction)buttonclick:(id)sender {

    [keyWordArray addObject:keyWordField.text];
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:keyWordArray forKey:@"Keywords"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

and

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSArray *array = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Keywords"];

    if (!array) {
        keyWordArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    } else {
        keyWordArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:nameArray];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are overriding your

```
[userDefaults setObject:keyWordField.text forKey:@"Keywords"];
```

every then and there your every object in the array will be referring to your `[userDefaults setObject:keyWordField.text forKey:@"Keywords"];` object thats y the problem comes

Comment: So what should i do now?

Comment: If you want to persist your data better add the whole array to userDefaults

Answer (score 0):

Because if you are navigate to another viewController. since the your user default value save in **second** only.

1. After pop to back through viewDidLoad is loaded. so far its have second string only save in User Default.

that way it display second only.

Answer (score 0):

You code is **overwrite** the last value and **remove previous values from NSUserDefault**. You have to use **array to stored all value** and you have save array into NSUserDefault.

```
NSMutableArray *aryDataDefault = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"YourKey"];
[aryDataDefault addObject:textfield.text];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:aryDataDefault forKey:@"YourKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```